# How do I get rid of seams in my procedural asteroid generator?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh, procedural-generation

I am coding a procedural asteroid generator in Unity using a custom mesh.

The main idea is taken from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QN39W020LqU) YouTube series, where you basically create your own cube with six evenly sub-divided sites, then normalize the vertices and apply a noise function. So far so good.

The problem appears to be a visible seam at the edges of the cube. Here is a screenshot:

[image: The visible seams between the faces]

I already figured out, that this comes from a bad normals calculation because normals can not be calculated properly for edge vertices.
 I tried to solve this by just making my original mesh two vertices bigger in each dimension, then running the `RecalculateNormals` function on this mesh, and then trying to get rid of the added triangles at the fringe.

You can find my code for generating one of the 6 sides below:

```
Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[(resolution + 2) * (resolution + 2)]; // We need a rim for correct normal generation!
int[] allTriangles = new int[(resolution - 1 + 2) * (resolution - 1 + 2) * 6]; // Mind the rim!
int[] filteredTriangles = new int[(resolution - 1) * (resolution - 1) * 6]; // Only the visible triangles
int triIndexAllTriangles = 0;
int triIndexFilteredTriangles = 0;

for (int y = -1; y < resolution + 1; y++) // We iterate over all (visible and invisible) vertices
{
    for (int x = -1; x < resolution + 1; x++)
    {
        int i = (x + 1) + ((y + 1) * (resolution + 2)); // Calculate the current vertex index
        Vector2 percent = new Vector2(x, y) / (resolution - 1); // We will work with a relative width of the grid
        Vector3 pointOnUnitCube = localUp + (percent.x - 0.5f) * 2 * axisA + (percent.y - 0.5f) * 2 * axisB; // Calculate the position of the point on the cube (the point is relative to a local upwards facing axis)
        Vector3 pointOnUnitSphere = pointOnUnitCube.normalized; // Make a sphere
        vertices[i] = shapeGenerator.CalculatePointOnPlanet(pointOnUnitSphere); // Calculate the height of the point with some noise function
                
        ///// Face Generation /////
        if (x != resolution - 1 + 1 && y != resolution - 1 + 1) // Do not calculate a face for the righmost or upmost row of vertices
        {
            if (!(x == -1 || x == resolution - 1 || y == -1 || y == resolution - 1)) // Filtered ("visible") triangles will be stored in a separate triangle buffer
            {
                filteredTriangles[triIndexFilteredTriangles] = i;
                filteredTriangles[triIndexFilteredTriangles+1] = i+resolution+1 + 2;
                filteredTriangles[triIndexFilteredTriangles+2] = i+resolution + 2;

                filteredTriangles[triIndexFilteredTriangles+3] = i;
                filteredTriangles[triIndexFilteredTriangles+4] = i+1;
                filteredTriangles[triIndexFilteredTriangles+5] = i+resolution+1 + 2;

                triIndexFilteredTriangles += 6;
            }

            allTriangles[triIndexAllTriangles] = i;
            allTriangles[triIndexAllTriangles+1] = i+resolution+1 + 2;
            allTriangles[triIndexAllTriangles+2] = i+resolution + 2;

            allTriangles[triIndexAllTriangles+3] = i;
            allTriangles[triIndexAllTriangles+4] = i+1;
            allTriangles[triIndexAllTriangles+5] = i+resolution+1 + 2;

            triIndexAllTriangles += 6;
        }
    }
}

// First store the vertices, then all (visible and invisible) triangles. Calculate the normals with all vertices and then overwrite the triangles with only the visible triangles
mesh.Clear();
mesh.vertices = vertices;
mesh.triangles = allTriangles;
mesh.RecalculateNormals();
mesh.triangles = filteredTriangles;
```

I am not sure if this is the right way to overwrite faces in a mesh. But as a matter of fact, this code still shows visible seams and I am not sure what I do wrong here.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot please?

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues I edited my post with a screenshot.